# how to set and get color from combobox for .NET?

Tags: .net, colors, combobox, delphi-prism, selectedindexchanged

I need to set and get color from combobox for .NET. So far it has not worked for me.

Here is list of color in the combobox item list:

```
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
Azure
Beige
Bisque
Black
BlanchedAlmond
Blue
BlueViolet
Brown
BurlyWood
CadetBlue
Chartreuse
Chocolate
Coral
CornflowerBlue
Cornslik
Crimson
Cyan
DarkBlue
DarkCyan
DarkGoldRod
DarkGray
DarkGreen
DarkKhaki
DarkMagenta
DarkOliveGreen
DarkOrange
DarkOrchid
DarkRed
DarkSalmon
DarkSeaGreen
DarkSlateBlue
DarkSlateGray
DarkTurquoise
DarkViolet
DeepPink
DeepSkyBlue
DodgerBlue
FireBrick
FloralWhite
ForestGreen
Fuchsia
Gainsboro
GhostWhite
Gold
GoldenRod
Gray
Green
GreenYellow
HoneyDew
HotPink
IndianRed
Indigo
Ivory
Khaki
Lavender
LavenderBlush
LawnGreen
LemonChiffon
LightBlue
LightCoral
LightCyan
LightGoldenRodYellow
LightGray
LightGreen
LightPink
LightSalmon
LightSeaGreen
LightSkyblue
LightSlateGray
LightSteelBlue
LightYellow
Lime
LimeGreen
Linen
Magenta
Maroon
MediumAquamarine
MediumBlue
MediumOrchid
MediumPurple
MediumSeaGreen
MediumSlateBlue
MediumSpringGreen
MediumTurquoise
MediumVioletRed
MidnightBlue
MintCream
MistyRose
Moccasin
NavajoWhite
Navy
OldLace
Olive
OliveDrab
Orange
OrangeRed
Orchid
PaleGoldenRod
PaleGreen
PaleTurquoise
PaleVioletRed
PapayaWhip
PeachPuff
Peru
Pink
Plum
PowderBlue
Purple
Red
RosyBrown
RoyalBlue
SaddleBrown
Salmon
SandyBrown
SeaGreen
SeaShell
Sienna
Silver
SkyBlue
SlateBlue
SlateGray
Snow
SpringGreen
SteelBlue
Tan
Teal
Thistle
Tomato
Transparent
Turquoise
Violet
Wheat
White
WhiteSmoke
Yellow
YellowGreen
```

Here is ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged or get event:

```
gFontColor : String;

method Maker.FontColorBoxChange(Sender: Object; e:System.EventArgs);
begin
  if (Sender as combobox).SelectedIndex =-1 then exit;

  gFOntCOlor := (Sender as combobox).Selectedvalue; 
end;
```

Here is how I set the combobox selectedValue :

```
FontColorBox.SelectedValue := gFontColor;
```

It doesn't work. I was able to do exactly that for font names and it works but not for color. I am staring at the code and can't seem to make any sense of it or get it to work - probably due to late night thanksgiving party. :)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get and set the selected item you must use the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) property

**Get**

```
 gFOntCOlor :=(Sender As ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
```

**Set**

```
 FontColorBox.SelectedItem:='Peru';
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** This works fine if all you are expecting is to store and retrieve data from selectedItem property of ComboBox. However, if you want the combobox to update automatically as well to reflect the item being set to selectedItem, then you must do the following.

```
FontColorBox.SelectedItem:='Peru';
FontColorBox.SelectedIndex := FontComboBox.FindString('Peru');
```

Above code will automatically set the item and update the ComboBox to show your current selectedItem on your winform.

Comment: @ RRUZ Will it also automatically change or update the selectedIndex property of the comboBox? That's what I am doing after setting selectedItem and the selectedIndex never updates or changes to the selectedItem's position.

Comment: Yes, setting the value of this property, will change the value of the `selectedIndex`.

Comment: @ RRUZ, It didn't change my selectedIndex in my program even though I set the SelectedItem for ComboBox.

Comment: Are you sure which the value that you are setting exist in the combobox?

Comment: @ RRUZ, Yes, I did. It accepted the string value but didn't update the combobox itself to reflect the changes. In fact, I even checked the SelectedIndex value after setting selectedItem and it never changed but kept its default value that I set which was 0. After I made the above changes, it works great.

Comment: @digitalanalog the SelectIndex must change if your update the SelectedItem value, try this code MessageBox.Show(String.Format('Before {0}',FontColorBox.SelectedIndex));
    FontColorBox.SelectedItem:='Peru';
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format('After {0}',FontColorBox.SelectedIndex));

Comment: @ RRUZ Yes, I did exactly that when I test ran my program to see what was being set to SelectedIndex. MessageBox kept showing 0 for before and after. My combobox has drawitem event assigned and it's property drawmode set to OwnerDrawFixed and DropDownStyle set to DropDownList. I don't know if any of that makes a difference in how combobox functions.

Comment: I set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList and still working in my test project. check this sample project http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12733424/WindowsApplication11.zip

Comment: @ RRUZ I downloaded your demo app and ran it. It did exactly what you said. But when I changed the drawmode to drawownerfixed, It didn't update when I clicked on the button. In fact, the selectedIndex didn't get updated either. Its value remained the same from the last time. Plus, the combobox itself didn't change after SelectedItem was set Peru.